# How do I use GridLayout in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, grid-layout

I tried making a GUI with Swing. But when I trief using GridLayout every element sudenly disappears and I don't know why. Can someone explain and/or provide a solution?

I've tried looking at the Tutorial for it, but it didn't help very much. and I experimented a bit around but still not working. :(

```
JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
JPanel pan3 = new JPanel();
JPanel pan4 = new JPanel();
JPanel pan5 = new JPanel();
add(pan1);
add(pan2);
add(pan3);
add(pan4);
add(pan5);
pan1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
pan2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
pan3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
pan4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
pan5.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
```

I expected having 1 Element in every 0-4 columns but it shows me a blank screen.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for working examples you can download and modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected having 1 Element in every 0-4 columns but it shows me a blank screen.

No. You have 5 Panels and each of them has a gridlayout.

```
pan1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1)); //pan1 gets a new GridLayout
pan2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1)); //pan2 gets a new GridLayout
pan3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1)); //...
pan4.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
pan5.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
```

You need:

```
setLayout(new GirdLayout(1,5);  //1 Row 5 Columns
add(pan1);
add(pan2);
add(pan3);
add(pan4);
add(pan5);
```